# Setup default format for java.util.date and java.sql.date toString() method

Tags: java, localization, java.util.date

I have to change date formats from yyyy.mm.dd to dd.mm.yyyy. 
Can I change default format of Date.toString method instead of change date.toString () by formatter.format in whole project ?

Comment: You should use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: You can create a  `SimpleDateFormat` class with static methode to use in whole project.

Comment: You can create your own MyDate class by extending Date class and override toString() method. And use MyDate everywhere.

Comment: As @JoelGeiser suggests, you should use `SimpleDateFormat`. Just remember the class is not thread safe, so if using in e.g. servlet, be careful with the implementation.

Comment: You cannot change the Date class but, if you are always in control of the instantiation of your Date objects, you can instantiate a derived class where you reimplement the method toString(). Having said that, I do not think that it is a good idea to use the toString() method to format your dates.

Comment: No, it's not possible. `toString()` method of class Date has no option to change its output format.